# Is there any way to subtract data from previous row to the current row and save it to current row

Tags: mysql

I have three columns:

```
monthly   fee   remaining
```

First row - condition :

```
subtract fee(row 0) from monthly(row 0) and stored in remaining(row 0)
```

Second row and onwards - condition :

```
subtract fee(this row) from remaining(previous row) and stored in remaining(this row)
```

What query should I use to perform this operation? I need help in this regard.

Comment: Please make your question clear and give it an example. Made other people easier to help you.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Why do you need to do the above? It may not be the best solution to your problem.

Comment: How do you recognise the **order** of the rows? Is there an ID column or a date column? (All this looks suspiciously like Excel...)

Comment: Do these records have an ID or date field as well, or should we draw the data from a list sorted on `monthly`, `fee` or `remaining`?

Answer (score 0):

Take two seperate subqueries on those two columns and with required information in both subqueries and give row number on that field(for which u want to do  this operation) in whatever way possible. Now do left join on those two subqueries based on rownumber and rownumber+1 on other, now u will get two columns in select with rownumber field and rownumber+1 field aside. Take the difference in other select as other field.

Hope u understand it. Please do it care fully and give order by on specific column for which u r doing this thing.

Comment: How do you achieve the `rownumber` in MySql?

Comment: little bit difficult for me. but ill try nd let you know.can you plz elaborate your answer with example.

Comment: we can achieve rownumber by setting. Variable like (select @rownumber:=0 ) as t then we can cross join it with main table

Answer (score 0):

If you are just going to do it in a select statement the code would actually look like

```
select @recordnumber:=@recordnumber+1 as recordnumber,
@curremaining:=if(@curremaining=0,Monthly,@remaining) prevremaining,
Monthly, Fee, @remaining:=@curremaining-Fee as remaining 
from Payments,(select @remaining:=0,@curremaining:=0,@recordnumber:=0) x;
```

You might need to have an order by when querying the records in that case just add the order by at the end of the sql statement. i.e

```
from Payments,(select @remaining:=0,@curremaining:=0,@recordnumber:=0) x
order by fieldtoorder;
```

Comment: i dont want to retrieve data from database. i am doing it at form level so just want to copy data from item1 of previous row to item2 of current row.